# Iterator freezing

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I'm currently developing a python bot, in which i have some code with a class that has the iterator methods.

```
buffer = []
def __iter__(self):
    return self
def __next__(self):
    incoming = str(self.irc.recv(1024), encoding='utf-8').split("\r\n")
    self.buffer += incoming
    last = self.buffer.pop(0) #This implements a FI-FO queue
    #perform operations to extract commands etc.
    return [message,command,trail]
```

I'm calling this class in an iterator which basically looks like:

```
for command in connection: #Connection is the name of the above class
    print(command)
```

What i'm observing is that the first 3 elements of the queue are iterated through, and then the rest are just left there, in the queue, not processed until a new element enters the queue, at which point the first element in the queue leaves (as if the last element pushed out the first).
I'm not sure if this is something to do with iterators, and i shouldn't be using them to perform this task (if not, then what should i be using), or whether this is another problem. Thanks for any help, Kunc.

Comment: `irc.recv` looks like something that could cause thread blocking, make sure you aren't waiting on data.

Comment: Do you really want `buffer` to be a class attribute, shared by all instances of this class? That seems like a very bad idea for something like this…

Comment: Yes. I've fixed it now by adding an if statement around the recv function checking the buffer is empty before adding to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is this:

Each time you advance your iterator, you `recv` one or more lines, then `return` just the last one of them. So at some point, you're going to have all the lines there are piled up in your queue, and then try to receive another hunk of data, which won't be forthcoming, so you'll just block forever.

Imagine the other side sent these three buffers:

```
'abc\ndef\nghi\n'
'jkl\n'
'mno\nprs\n'
```

So, the first time through, you'll receive `'abc\ndef\nghi\n'`, split that into three lines, and return `'abc'`.

The second time, you'll receive `'jkl\n'`, split that into one more line and append it, and return `'def'`.

The third time, you'll receive `'mno\nprs\n'`, split that into two more lines and append them, and return `'ghi'`.

The fourth time, you'll wait forever to receive the next line.

What you need to do here is not `recv` again until you're out of lines.

---

However, you have a second problem. There is absolutely nothing that guarantees that each buffer will end on a newline. So you could easily be splitting lines in half. What you want to do is something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.lines, self.buf = [], ''
    # existing code
def __next__(self):
    if not self.lines:
        newbuf = str(self.irc.recv(1024), encoding='utf-8')
        if newbuf:
            self.buf += newbuf
            self.lines = self.buf.split("\r\n")
            self.buf = self.lines.pop()
    last = self.lines.pop(0)
    # etc.
```

---

Or, far more simply:

```
def __init__(self):
    # existing code
    self.rfile = self.irc.makefile('r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\r\n')
def close(self):
    self.rfile.close()
    # existing code
def __next__(self):
    return self.rfile.readline()
```

Because the code I wrote is exactly what `socket.makefile` does, except that it wraps it up in a complete file-like object (`io.TextIOWrapper`, in this case).